# Why is my RxJava observable not firing off subscribers?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm messing around with RxJava and I want to stream a thousand consecutive integers. Then I want to asynchronously split them into odd and even streams, and then print them asynchronously.

However, I'm getting nothing printed out or at least very partial output. What am I missing? Did I schedule incorrectly? Or is the console having multithreading issues in Eclipse?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0,1000).mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable<Integer> ints = Observable.from(values).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

    Observable<Integer> evens = ints.filter(i -> Math.abs(i) % 2 == 0);
    Observable<Integer> odds = ints.filter(i -> Math.abs(i) % 2 != 0);

    evens.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i + " IS EVEN " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    odds.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i + " IS ODD " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting the processing pipeline using `Schedules.computation` which runs daemon threads. Thus when your `main` thread finishes, those threads are terminated before processing your observable.

So if you would like to see your results printed you could have your main thread wait for the results (e.g. by `Thread.sleep`) or subscribe on the calling thread by removing `subscribeOn`. There is also an option to create your own scheduler which will run non-daemon threads.

Comment: ohhhh... well I need to tell the main thread to wait up then. One sec, let me try that.

Comment: Or subscribe on the current thread instead of another scheduler. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I added a `Thread.sleep()` at the end of the `main()` method, just to give the stream a chance to run. Thanks! It worked.

Comment: I was trying to emulate an asynchronous environment so I didn't want it to run on the main thread. I guess I was expecting the application to stay alive much like a threadpool that has not been shutdown.

Comment: I'm curious, why do `Schedulers` not behave the same way as an `ExecutorService`? The `ExecutorService` having active threads will keep an application alive even if the main daemon thread finishes. But with `Schedulers` everything terminates when the main thread finishes...

Comment: @ThomasN. `Scheduler` is just an abstraction designed specifically to Rx needs and doesn't translate 1:1 to what `ExecutorService` is designed to do. You can actually [create a scheduler from an executor](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html#from(java.util.concurrent.Executor)).